# How do you wrap an achor tag in Vue2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using Vue 2 and I am using an anchor tag as a "button" (for styling purposes with an svg).

The drawback of using an anchor tag in this way is that you can't disable it in the same way as a button.

I would like to make a vue component that simply wraps an anchor tag. I would like the component to pass all properties of the custom component onto the child anchor tag so that someone can use it like this:

```
<custom-comp id="closeButton" title="Close" class="c-btn" @click="close" :disable="true"></custom-comp>
```

I want to intercept the `click` on the child anchor tag and only emit that if the component is not disabled.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `disable` property is used only in form elements. What you're looking for here is to use `v-if`:

```
<a id="closeButton" title="Close" class="c-btn" @click="close" v-if="isConditionMatched">
    Only show if isConditionMatched returns true
</a>
```

Or, conditionally you can use `return false` statement inside your method:

```
close() {
  if(!isConditionMatched) return false;
  // continue your close function
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is not about showing or hiding the anchor tag. I want to try get the same behaviour as disable on a button.

Comment: you can try second option

Comment: That does not look like a custom component - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-Components